# групповая рассылка сообщений

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Ведется рассылка сообщений пользователям. Пользователи берутся из текстового файла. В текстовом файл состоит из построчных email адресов.

```
emaillist = open('/path/list_address.txt', 'r').readlines()
```

и рассылаются

```
for email in emaillist:
    aws.send(email, "noreply@mail.com")
```

была создана бд  в sqlalchemy

```
class Subscribe(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    companyname = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Subscribe('{self.companyname}', '{self.email}')"
```

Подскажите, как настроить emaillist для рассылки из базы

Answer (score 3):

Есть пару моментов, но?

```
for subscribe in Subscribe.query.yield_per(1000):
    aws.send(subscribe.email)
```

Comment: что за моменты?

Comment: Ну например, каждый новый запуск будет отсылать заново emails. А может лучше только тем которым раньше не отсылали этот email?